# Trying to control scaling for a nested SVG element

Tags: html, svg

An application I'm working on uses a simple SVG to represent a reported value within set upper and lower bounds as a square on top of a horizontal line. The elements are then rendered within an HTML  which has a fixed vertical dimension but adaptive horizontal. The SVG currently scales as a single object, meaning that the square can be squashed or stretched into a rectangle, which I'd like to avoid. I've been trying to use nested SVG elements with defined viewports and viewboxes so that I can control the aspect ratio of the square, but I'm having no luck.

Here's my latest attempt:

```html
<svg class="va-kpv-graph-image" viewBox="0 0 400 50" preserveAspectRatio="none" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <svg>
        <line x1="0" y1="25" x2="400" y2="25" style="stroke:black; stroke-width: 2px" /> 
        <line x1="1" y1="0" x2="1" y2="50" style="stroke:black; stroke-width: 2px" />
        <line x1="399" y1="0" x2="399" y2="50" style="stroke:black; stroke-width: 2px" />
    </svg>

    <svg x="154" y="0" width="42" height="50" viewbox="0 0 42 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
            <rect x="1" y="5" width="40" height="40" rx="10" ry="10" style="fill:blue; stroke:black;stroke-width:2px" />
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or if I'm just misunderstanding something about this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: for clarification, the three lines should be allowed to scale without preserving the aspect ratio and the overall SVG should always fill the area taken up by the div. It's just the square that should keep its aspect.

Comment: If you want to preserve the aspect ratio a) don't specify preserveAspectRatio="none" because that specifically states you don't want to preserve aspect ratio b) specify a viewBox because preserveAspectRatio has no effect without a viewBox

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried removing the viewbox and preserveAspectRatio from the outer element and setting them on the first inner element. This left me with lines which filled the div area and scaled freely, but the square remained fixed relative to the origin and didn't scale at all. Is it possible to get the behaviour in my edit above using only these attributes?